# what happens to the data logs if set 'log.cleanup.policy' to both 'delete' and 'compact' when I'm using time based retention policy

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand, how the does compaction and log clean up happens if I set the 'log.cleanup.policy' to have both 'delete' and 'compact' at the same time when I'm using time based retention policy.

Let's say our retention period is 7 days (the default one) and during these 7 days I've below pattern for my data flow, Please help me understand how does it look after 7 days.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use both compact and delete as a `log.cleanup.policy`. Logs will be compacted in background periodically to retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition. Compaction can be configured with this config parameters:

**log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms**: The minimum time a message will remain uncompacted in the log

**log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms**: The maximum time a message will remain ineligible for compaction in the log

As you have already said, for your example:

Before compaction:

[image]

After compaction:

[image]

Logs will **also** be deleted after `log.retention.hours` period without considering whether or not it is compacted. Log retention is checked according to this parameter:

**log.retention.check.interval.ms**: The frequency in milliseconds that the log cleaner checks whether any log is eligible for deletion (default is 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the below KIP,  all the keys that haven't been updated for some time to be automatically expired. That's why we would have only three keys ( which were updated during this time) and their corresponding values after the retention time period is met.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015